# How to understand fedora rpm macro with parameter?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I find no example of things such as `(n:)` and `-n` in RPM syntax references? How can I understand this macro? Where can I find the syntax details manual of this macro?

```
%ldconfig_scriptlets(n:) %{?ldconfig:\
%ldconfig_post %{?*} %{-n:-n %{-n*}}\
%ldconfig_postun %{?*} %{-n:-n %{-n*}}\
}
```

It's from `/usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.ldconfig`

Comment: I don't have an exact answer but http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/macros.html may help. I am _fairly_ sure the `%{-n:-n ...}` say "if there's an `-n` flag add it as well as blah blah blah...

Comment: The best documentation is at https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/macros.html